# Python3 cant detect<class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

I am running some python3 code which will occasionally get a list, dict, and None.

```
        fieldType = type(raw_data[root_key].get("oslc_cm:ChangeRequest"))
        print('fieldType=')
        print(fieldType)
        if fieldType is None:
            print('its none')
        else:
            print('its not none')
```

this works for everything except when fieldType is 'None':

```
fieldType=
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
its not none
#this output works as expected
```

but when fieldType is `<class 'NoneType'>` it reports it as being 'not none'

```
fieldType=
<class 'NoneType'>
its not none
```

why cant my code correctly identify when an object is of type 'None'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fieldType` is `<class 'NoneType'>`, which is different from `None`. It can never be `None`, because `type` always returns some type.

Looks like you want

```
raw_data[root_key].get("oslc_cm:ChangeRequest") is None
```

instead of

```
fieldType is None
```

Answer (score 1):

`None != type(None)`

`type(None)` is a `<class 'type'>` object. The correct way to chech a type of a variable in python is to use `isinstance()`. Then your code would look like this:

```py
NoneType = type(None)
fieldType = type(raw_data[root_key].get("oslc_cm:ChangeRequest"))
print('fieldType=')
print(fieldType)
if isinstance(fieldType, NoneType):
    print('its none')
else:
    print('its not none')
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a common mistake. The proper way to test for a value being None is to use is or is not, not using equality tests:

```
if fieldType is None:
    print('its none')
else:
    print('its not none')
```

the `get()` method returns `None` (and hence evaluates to `False`) when there are no items in the dictionary. This means you'd get the same result by using `if not raw_data[root_key].get("oslc_cm:ChangeRequest")`: which means "if there's no entry for `oslc_cm:ChangeRequest in raw_data[root_key]`". Because of this, you can write your code like this instead:

```
    fieldType = type(raw_data[root_key].get("oslc_cm:ChangeRequest"))
    if fieldType is not None:
        print('its not none')
    else:
        print('its none')
```

Comment: The question is already using `is None` in its test. The problem is that `fieldType` is a type, so it can be `type(None)` which is not `None` itself.